# Close dropdown when other dropdown is opened

Tags: javascript, dropdown

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/qesr0ybf/

```
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}

/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When one dropdown is open, the other can be opened at the same time. I'm trying to make the other one close and have only one open at a time. How can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your function to this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var d2 = document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList;
    if(d2.contains("show")) d2.toggle("show");
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

and the other function similarly.

i.e, check if the other dropdown contains the class `show` and then remove it.

A better approach would be to keep track of the last opened dropdown and close it before opening another but since you've just two dropdowns so this should do.

Live demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qesr0ybf/2/)